# How to show float values with pandas.read_sql from a sqlite query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, formatting

I need to get this result for an assignment using python/sqlite3.
[required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKcYe.png)

I did my query in MYSQL, and I  got the answer already to the assignment question. Since I am learning, I find it easier to do the queries using MySQL Workbench first.
[result in MySQLWorkbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex24C.png)

However, When I try to do it in Jupyter notebook with Sqlite3, it only shows the zeros on the percentage column.
I am using the function pd.read_sql_query. I went to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas-read-sql-query) and could not find any arguments there that would do what I want, or I did not understand it. I played with the coarse_float argument, but it did not make a difference. I am learning, so sometimes, I do not understand the documentation completely.

query_results  = pd.read_sql_query(query1,conn)

This is what I get in my Jupyter notebook:
[Output un Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAk35.png)

I know the numbers are there because if I multiple the column ”percentage_female_only_movie” fly 100, I see them.  I would like to know how to show them like in MYSQLWorkbench.

Thank you for any help. An if you know any link where I can learn about this type of issues, I would love if you can share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to CAST the numerator and denominator of the column I was generating in SELECT statement of my query.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4) AS Movie_year,
    ROUND(CAST(fcm.Female_Cast_Only_Movies*100 AS FLOAT)/ CAST(tm.movies_total AS FLOAT),2) AS Percentage_Female_only_Movie,
   tm.movies_total As Total_movies
```

FROM Movie AS m

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r6cV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try df[colname] = df[colname].astype(float).

This would convert your column to float and you should see the values

Comment: I tried it before and it did not work. ""q11b_results  = pd.read_sql_query(q11b,conn)
q11b_results["Percentage_Female_only_Movie"].astype(float)""". I also tried """pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.4}".format""", but it did not work either